# How embed External web page in a mobile web page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I am trying to embed an external webpage with in a mobile web page.

I tried with Iframe with in a div, it works fine with few smart phone devices, but for few others ( like note ...) its works but having issue with clicking on hyperlink of the external site. What I could find the external web page area what ever gets loads in Iframe with hyperlink, the hyperlinks reminds same invisible, that is even if scroll the page, page moves but the hyper link does not work for click. Only able to click the position where the hyperlinks got loaded in Iframe.

Then i tried with Object, got stuck with height and width of the object. Does go with 100% width and height and cannot scroll further both x and Y direction even page got more to scroll.

third i tried with jquery onload() in a div

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>$("#testLoad").load("test.htm");    </script>
```

still im not able to solve the problem.

Please can any one help

Comment: Why do you need an iframe, what kind of content is it? Usually a simple PHP include may suffice - especially if it's a content management issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax for getting html content and replace the data in page by using jQuery function .html() or .text()

Comment: what about the page styles?

Comment: css will able to handle it... just include css link in your page.